# Python for loop efficiency

Tags: python, performance, loops, csv, for-loop

I have this block of code, which works, but takes about 8 seconds to execute. I know that it is the second `for` loop, since there is a loop inside of a loop. However, I believe that I need both loops, because I need to cross-reference the `tracks` list.

Does anybody know of a way to make this function execute faster? I can't seem to see another way of writing it.

**FYI** : The csv file that I am using has 5570 lines, which is another reason for the function taking a "while".

Thanks in advance!

```
def load_library(filename) :
    library = open(filename, 'rb')
    reader = csv.reader(library, delimiter = '|')
    tracks = set([])
    albums = set([])
    albums1 = set([])
    #albums1 is the set of albums which have already been added to the albums list.

    for row in reader : 
        artist, track, album, genre, year = row
        track = Track(artist, track)
        track.set_album(album)
        tracks.add(track)

    library = open(filename, 'rb')
    reader = csv.reader(library, delimiter = '|')

    for row in reader : 
        artist, track, album, genre, year = row
        a = Album(artist, album)
        for i in tracks :
            if str(i.album) == str(a.title) :
                a.add_track(i.title)
                if album not in albums1 :
                    albums.add(a)
        albums1.add(album)

    return tracks, albums
```

After using c.Profile :

> > > cProfile.run('load_library()')
> > >                224565 function calls in 9.776 seconds

```
   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.002    0.002    9.776    9.776 <string>:1(<module>)
     5570    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 musiclib.py:18(set_album)
    11140    0.007    0.000    0.007    0.000 musiclib.py:23(__init__)
    92784    0.028    0.000    0.037    0.000 musiclib.py:31(add_track)
     5570    0.004    0.000    0.009    0.000 musiclib.py:6(__init__)
        1    9.723    9.723    9.775    9.775 musiclib.py:71(load_library)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_csv.reader}
    16710    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
    92784    0.009    0.000    0.009    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {open}
```

Comment: Well, it is faster to use `readline(line_num)` then to use a `for` loop for going through each line.

Comment: Try profiling it with `cProfile` to see which parts are slow.

Comment: @AHuman Thank you, but how would I use `readline(line_num)` to read every line?

Comment: It is up to you. But you can just use 5570 more lines. I would just make a new python file and then just import it over and run a function with 5571 lines with the last line returning your result. That way your program looks clean.

Comment: @sweeneyrod I put my filename within the function because I was getting a syntax error. Nevertheless, still the same output. I edited the post with the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this all in only one for-loop:

```
def load_library(filename) :
    library = open(filename, 'rb')
    reader = csv.reader(library, delimiter = '|')
    tracks = set([])
    albums = {}

    for row in reader : 
        artist, track, album, genre, year = row
        if album not in albums:
            a = Album(artist, album)
            albums[album] = a
        else:
            a = albums[album]
        a.add_track(track)
        track = Track(artist, track)
        track.set_album(album)
        tracks.add(track)
    return tracks, set(albums.values())
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it takes only 0.705 seconds to execute.